# How does this expression will be calculated

Tags: java

I have an expression with compound assignment as

x += 2*5

so how it will be evaluated is it

x = (x + 2) * 5

or

x = x + (2 * 5)

and why?

Comment: Is this a serious question? I mean, try & run this piece to see what the result is. Also, search for operator precedence in java to know what happens. multiplication will take place first followed by addition, I think.

Comment: The *how* can be easily checked yourself by compiling and running that code. The *why* is a valid question though (which has been answered already).

Comment: @shahkalpesh. I want an answer with the reason. so to have context i asked the result as well.

Comment: And the reason is? operator precedence?

Comment: @gurukulki: Sorry, I was rude to you & didn't realize it. Apologies.

Comment: @shahkalpeh. No problem. I got what I wanted, nothing personal. thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An expression of the form

```
x += expr;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x + (expr);
```

So in this case it's

```
x = x + (2 * 5);
```

It would be *very* weird and confusing if the current value of `x` was used for part of the expression implicitly.

Comment: Jon: Do you think such questions make sense? Isn't operator precedence documentation & runtime (to see the result of this example) enough to understand?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: I believe it was a question honestly asked, even if it's one to which I personally find the answer obvious. I'm sure that when I was first learning to program I had some similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Any expression in the form of `var op= expr` is evaluated to `var = var op expr`. This is defined in the java specification [15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2).

Answer (score 1):

I see the phrase "operator precedence" mentioned, and I believe this is confusing the issue. Consider this:

```
x *= a + b;
```

Even though `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, this is still evaluated as

```
x = x * (a + b)
```

The full explanation is given in [JLS 15.26.2 Compound Assignment Operatos](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.26.2):

> *E1 op= E2* is equivalent to *E1 = (T)((E1) op (E2))*, where *T* is the type of *E1*, except that *E1* is evaluated only once